# Why are my video files getting bigger after converting to np.array?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have video files around 700x200, and I'm using cv2 to perform preprocessing. The actual videos are .mp4 format and range from a couple mb depending on the length, but after scaling down the resolution, making the color videos grey, somehow my filesize almost 10x when I try to either save via `Pickle` or `np.save`.

Preprocessing code is:

```
def save_video(link):

    frames = []

    # Creating a VideoCapture object to read the video
    # cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
    frameCount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    frameWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frameHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    buf_c = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8'))
    buf = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth), np.dtype('uint8'))

    fc = 0
    ret = True

    # Resolution reduction
    scale_percent = 30 # percent of original size
    width = int(buf.shape[2] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(buf.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)

    while (fc < frameCount and ret):
        ret, buf_c[fc] = cap.read()
        buf[fc] = cv2.cvtColor(buf_c[fc], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        resized = cv2.resize(buf[fc], dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frames.append(resized)
        fc += 1

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    return frames // or np.asarray(frames)
```

dimensions for video files as examples (after processing):

`(844, 216, 121)` (so 844 frames of 216x121 after scaling down)

`(788, 216, 121)`

Actual video files are 1-2MB before any preprocessing and the resulting pkl or npy are 10x+ in size. Is this what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Video is highly compresssed and efficient. Pickle and `npy` are uncompressed. It makes a massive difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compressed video stream is decompressed by OpenCV and is saved as raw data. To reduce the size you need to encode the video stream. For example:

```
def opencv_replay(video_file: str, video_file_out: str):
    import cv2

    video_in = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
    video_out = cv2.VideoWriter()

    assert (video_out.open(
        video_file_out,
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('a', 'v', 'c', '1'),
        video_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS),
        (int(video_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(video_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    ))

    while True:
        res, frame = video_in.read()

        if not res:
            break

        video_out.write(frame)
```

`avc1` is used for h264 encoding in Linux.